# D3JS Testing - enter() is not fired

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have some trouble setting up tests with D3JS, here is the code I'd like to test :

```
function drawCityWindow(city,scale){
  var d3cityWindow = d3.select(".svg").selectAll(".d3city-window").data(city);

  d3cityWindow.enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", function (d) {
        return d.id+"-window"
    })
```

}

And here is my test unit, where I want to test the presence in DOM of the  :

```js
it("should test the drawCityWindow method",function () {
        var city = description["cities"][0];
        drawCityWindow(city,1);
        expect($('#'+city.id+'-window')[0]).toBeInDOM()
    })
```

I'm using the famous jasmine-jquery lib to retrieve DOM objects, and I figured out that when I ran the tests, the enter() function was never fired.

Have you some clues about this issue ?

Comment: d3 side looks fine to me may be you can console.log to see if the function is getting called, another possibility is that the cities array is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, the function is called and with a city defined, I just checked after seeing your comment. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Silly question: is ".svg" a class of what element?

Comment: It's an html tag used to handle SVG graphics : http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp

Comment: So, remove the dot. When you write `select("svg")` you are selecting the SVG element, but when you write `select(".svg")` you are only selecting something with a class "svg". But removing the dot alone will not work: you cannot append HTML elements (like "div") to an SVG.

Comment: That's right, I select the svg tag by its class, which I set to svg. I'll change this, but it's not the source of the issue. And I may be mistaken, but it seems I can append div tags inside svg tags (it shows up in the HTML source code)

Comment: Yes, you can append a "div", "p", "h1" or anything, and it will show up when you inspect the node. But it will have no effect in the SVG itself, unless you use `foreignObject`. If you look at the same link you shared in your comment it shows, under "SVG reference", all valid elements.

Comment: That's absolutely right, thanks for pointing this up. I'll take a look on the foreignObject properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue was a little bit tricky : I passed a `city` data set to d3js instead of putting it in an array like `[city]`.

That is, I think d3js iterated over the keys of the `city` object, and not on the object itself.

Thanks a lot for your help !